# Difference between removeDialog(), dismissDialog() and dismiss()

Tags: java, android

What is different between `removeDialog()` and `dismiss()` and `dismissDialog()`? because I'm able to use them together without any problem.

And is it matter when implementing `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` or `AlertDialog.OnClickListener`?

I searched a lot but couldn't find anything useful.

**EDIT:**
I'm developing for Android 2.3.

**Example code:**

```
public final class OptionsPreference extends PreferenceActivity implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener
{
private AlertDialog noInternetDialog = null;
//...

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        if (this.noInternetDialog != null)
        {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Destroying noInternetDialog...");
            this.noInternetDialog.dismiss(); // X?
            removeDialog(DIALOG_NOINTERNET); // X?
            dismissDialog(DIALOG_NOINTERNET); // X?
            this.noInternetDialog = null;
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected final Dialog onCreateDialog(final int id)
    {
        switch (id)
        {
            case DIALOG_NOINTERNET:
            {
                final AlertDialog.Builder _builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info).setMessage(R.string.str_nointernet);
                _builder.setCancelable(false);
                _builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.str_wifisettings, this);
                _builder.setNeutralButton(R.string.str_ok, this);
                this.noInternetDialog = _builder.create();
                if (!isFinishing())
                {
                    this.noInternetDialog.show();
                }
                return this.noInternetDialog;
            }
// ...
}
```

Comment: I can only see dismiss() inside the Dialog class, where are the other two coming from?

Comment: Could you please provide the links to the documentation for removeDialog() and dismissDialog() methods?

Comment: Added code, and from "android.app.Activity.dismissDialog" and "android.app.Activity.removeDialog" package.

Comment: Oh, got it now. dismissDialog() and removeDialog() inside Activity have been deprecated a long time ago, please don't use them. Just call dismiss() on the Dialog instance.

Comment: Im dev. ing for Android 2.3.3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106860/discussion-between-egor-and-yousha-aleayoub).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dismissDialog(int id)` : Dismisses the dialog with the specified id. It only hides the dialog  but still keeps the internal references by the Activity which contains this dialog so that it can be restored in future.Deprecated in API 13.

`removeDialog(int id)` : It also dismisses the dialog with the specified id. Means it hides that particular dialog and in addition cleans up all the references by the Activity and hence cannot be restored in future. Deprecated in API 13.

`dismiss()` : This method operates on a particular dialog because it is a method of Dialog class. It also dismisses the dialog. You have to own a valid dialog in order to dismiss it else you'll get exception.